# Update database automatically before loading page

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla2.5

I'd like to update (e.g. dates or upcoming events etc.) in some tables in my database  automatically before loading the rest of the page. For example the first time every Monday someone gets on the website.
Before I used joomla I had a php-script which I included at the beginning of every page and that worked pretty well. 
But with joomla I don't know where to insert the (adjusted) script. Should I create a (content) plugin? But where/how would I trigger it?

Thank you

Comment: why not just make it static to update every monday at a certain time as a maintenance script?

Comment: You could use a cron job to run a PHP file script every Monday. I have a cron job running to delete zip files generated every hour and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Or if you want the php script to run on each page every time, you could just add it to your index.php file. This can be found in website_root/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/index.php

Comment: thank you for the answers
@Fallenreaper: what do you mean by maintenance  script? how would I run it?

Comment: @Lodder: I didn't know about cron job, but I would need access to the shell, which I probably won't get. I'm not the main admin of the website, I just maintain a subdomain.

Comment: @ASmith: That's what I did before I used Joomla, but if I include the script in the index.php of the template, I would stop working I somebody changes the template?

Comment: I like the idea of with the cron job, if I get it working, I'll definitly give it a try. But I still think creating some sort of plugin (or module?) would be better. Because I have to update the parameters of the scripts every couple of weeks. And if I could do that with a UI on the admin page, anybody could maintain it without knowledge of the source code.

Comment: @josh21 Yes if you change the template then a different index.php file would be used. If you want to create a plugin, take a look at this page http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using a cron job that calls a view especially made for this task. Using the URL with `&format=raw` so that no unnecessary joomla html gets loaded